# How to set HTTP status code with JSF?

Tags: jsf-2, http-status-codes

I use Apache Myfaces 2.2 on WebSphere Application Server.

I have a JSF page, which "test" the conenction to filesystem and database.

When the connection fails, I want to return another HTTP Status Code. 
How can I do this with JSF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  response.setStatus();

for more details this link will be helpful :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16777616/1763602