# Response object in JSF

Tags: jsp, jsf, response.redirect

I feel like this is going to be a question to which the shortest answer will be : "that's why JSF replaced JSP", but I'll just go ahead and ask it.

**Question :** I am wondering : could I obtain the Response object of a JSF page (if there's any) ?

**Why wonder ?** : I found myself in a situation where I need to to pass from a JSF page to a JSP one, so I thought why not redirect (with `response.sendRedirect`) from a bean that gets invoked from the JSF page and then... you can see where it's heading.

I feel like this can be done in a cleaner way, can't see how though !

**EDIT :** while on it, I'll also ask about which way would be best for redirecting from to JSF pages.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Not sure to understand the real problem, but I can suggest to use `<h:outputLink>` as shown [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-link-commandlink-and-outputlink-example/).

Comment: Actually I meant the question to be of a general order, so anything about redirecting in JSF will do me good :) So outputLink replaces the `<a>` tag, now what about redirecting from inside a bean ?

Comment: You can obtain the response object in the managed bean by calling `HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse()` (obtained from [How to stream a file download in a JSF backing bean?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9394237/1065197)) and then perform operations on the `HttpServletResponse` object. Obviously, there are things that you can't do like sending a redirect from an ajax request.

Comment: Ok. This is weird, same answer from two guys in practically the same time... If you can post it as an answer it so I could at least be able to upvote it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, if you want to get the `response` object, you can have it in `JSF` like bellow!

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
```

But you don't really need to get the `response` object only to redirect outside of `JSF`. This can be done more easily with the following:

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
externalContext.redirect("http://www.example.com/myJspPage.jsp");
```

***Edit***:

When you are in any **non-action** method, you can use any of the above! But when you are in any **action** method, the proper `JSF` way of redirecting is:

```
public String goToOutsideAction(){
    ....
    return "/myPage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"
}
```

The method should return a context-relative view ID and the target must be a JSF page.

Comment: Thanks, `page.xhtml?faces-redirect=true` works as well, which one is best ?

Comment: Yup! Ofcourse, `return "url.com/page.jsp?faces-redirect=true"` is the proper jsf way to handle redirect, for details you can see the answer of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277366/what-is-the-difference-between-redirect-and-navigation-forward-and-when-to-use-w) question.

Comment: Mind me asking though, could redirecting to a JSP page from a JSF one be cause for trouble ?

Comment: @Gloserio nope, it will just generate a GET request on the JSP page.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : so what about the beans that were in the JSF page when you redirect to a JSP, do they suffer nothing in particular ? How do they behave ?

Comment: The code in your edit is completely wrong. The method can't be `void` and the outcome can't be a full URL. It must be a context-relative view ID and the target must be a JSF page, not a "plain JSP" page as the code seems to suggest. JSP is deprecated since JSF 2.0, so it's really strange to see a JSF 2.0 targeted piece of code which still uses JSP.

Comment: @BalusC : so should not navigate from JSF page to JSP page ?

Comment: Replace "should" by "can". Note that this is exactly the whole reason why the OP posted this question.

Comment: Can not ? Why not ? What's the hasard ?

Comment: @BalusC, Yes. I see, you are right (Some how I missed it to get earlier). And the `void` was a typing mistake.. :P Anyways thank you very much for your suggestions. And I just edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the response object in the managed bean by calling

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse()
```

Code adapted from [How to stream a file download in a JSF backing bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9394237/1065197))

Once you have the response object you can perform any operations on it like changing the headers. Obviously, there are things that you can't do like sending a redirect from an ajax request.

Comment: Thanks, would it be ok with you if I marked @Sarradur Rahaman 's answer as the accepted one ? It seems he was the first...